# JavaScript if statement didn't work

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, console.log

I have a function as below

```js
function test (x){
  if(x==='a' || x!=='b' ||'c')
  {
    console.log('result');
    console.log(x);
  }
  else {
    console.log('wrong') 
  } 
}

test('123');
```

And I expect the output will log "wrong", but it log //result 123 as the picture below. I'm not sure is because the if condition can't work like this?

[image]

Comment: What do you think `x !== 'b' || 'c'` will do?

Comment: 'c' is truthy. No matter what x is, if is always true

Comment: @bambam `'c'` is *truthy* not `true`.

Comment: should be:  if(x==='a' || x!=='b' || x!== ''c')

Answer (score 2):

`'c'` will always resolve to true. You're basically saying,

> does `'c'` equate to a truthy value?

...which of course it does (it's a non-empty string). [Read about truthy/falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

You probably assumed that this part of the condition would "borrow" the previous (b's) `||`. This doesn't happen.

So you need `x === 'c'`.

However, you have mixed logic. Are you quite sure you meant `!== 'b'` rather than `=== 'b'`? This means the condition will resolve to true if you pass ANYTHING other than 'b', since you're using only 'or' operators.

In conclusion, you probably meant:

```
if( x === 'a' || x === 'b' || x === 'c')
```

Which can be reduced to

```
if (['a', 'b', 'c'].includes(x))
```

Or indeed

```
if (/^[abc]$/.test(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last condition is `'c'` which is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

```
Boolean('c');
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using OR statement. So obvisiously `x(=123) !== 'b'` and `'c'` is also true .

So thats why the result is 123

Answer (score -1):

Modify your if statement to the following
if(x==='a' || x!=='b' || x!=='c')

Comment: In this case 2nd and 3th statements are both true.